# Why is my DB2 Create Table w/ Foreign Key failing?

Tags: sql, db2

This is the statement that's failing:

```
CREATE TABLE QS36F.BWMEMBERS ( 
   ID         NUMERIC(9,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   GROUP_ID   NUMERIC(9,0) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID)
        REFERENCES QS36F.BWGROUPS(ID) 
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
   EMP_ID     NUMERIC(7,0) NOT NULL,
       FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID)
            REFERENCES QS36F.GLEMPSIG(ESIGEMP)
       ) RCDFMT MEMBERSR;
```

Error I'm receiving:

```
Message: [SQL0573] Table GLEMPSIG in QS36F does not have a matching parent key. Cause . . . . . :   A referencing column list was specified in the FOREIGN KEY clause for constraint Q_QS36F_BWMEMBERS_EMP_ID_00001 in QS36F. The parent table GLEMPSIG in QS36F does not have a matching PRIMARY or UNIQUE key. If the file is partitioned, the access path of the parent file must be non-partitioned. The constraint cannot be added. Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try the request again: -- Specify a table in the FOREIGN KEY clause that has a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key that matches the referencing column list. -- Change the referencing column list to match the definition of the PRIMARY or UNIQUE key defined on the parent table. -- If the parent file is partitioned, add a non-partitioned access path.
```

The first **FOREIGN KEY** works (on a fresh table I just created) but the second doesn't. The **GLEMPSIG** table wasn't created using SQL (existing IBM physical file) but **GLSIGEMP.ESIGEMP** does seem to be designated as both UNIQUE and as the primary key.  **BWMEMBERS.EMP_ID** and **GLSIGEMP.ESIGEMP** are both the same data type. I don't understand the error message or what I need to do for this to work. Any help appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: (DDS from GLEMPSIG.PF)

```
 A                                      UNIQUE
 A          R EMPSIGR                   TEXT('EMPLOYEE SIGNATURES')
 A            ESIGEMP        7S 0       COLHDG('EMPLOYEE')
 A                                      TEXT('EMPLOYEE')
 A            ESIGFIR       20A         COLHDG('FIRST NAME')
 A                                      TEXT('FIRST NAME')
 A            ESIGMI         1A         COLHDG('MIDDLE INITIAL')
 A            ESIGLAS       20A         COLHDG('LAST NAME')
 A                                      TEXT('LAST NAME')
 A            ESIGSIG        5A         COLHDG('SIGNATURE')
 A                                      TEXT('SIGNATURE')
 A          K ESIGEMP
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for `QS36F.GLEMPSIG`

Comment: just added the DDS code that was used to create it, it's not SQL. Also, I tried running ALTER TABLE QS36F.GLEMPSIG ALTER ESIGEMP SET NOT NULL which although it ran successfully did not solve the problem

Comment: Do you have Primary Key or Unique Constraint (not just unique index) on `ESIGEMP`? Look at the [QSYS2.SYSCST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcatsyscst.htm) and [QSYS2.SYSKEYCST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcatkeycst.htm) system views.

Comment: I didn't find anything in either of those tables, (WHERE system_table_schema='QS36F' AND SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME='GLEMPSIG') so we could be on the right track. Any command(s) I can run to possibly resolve this? ALTER TABLE QS36F.GLEMPSIG ADD PRIMARY KEY (ESIGEMP);?

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark, that seemed to do the trick. I ran ALTER TABLE QS36F.GLEMPSIG ADD PRIMARY KEY (ESIGEMP); and now it's letting me create the members table like I want, including the update restrict and cascading delete.